# Can't set UIView's background color Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view that I initialise like this:

```
var view: UIView! = {
    var perm = UIView()

    perm.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    // enable auto layout
    perm.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return perm
}()
```

After that I add a label as a subview to `view`. The label is initialised like this:

```
var title: UILabel! = {
    let perm = UILabel()
    perm.textColor = UIColor.white
    perm.numberOfLines = 0
    perm.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

    // enable auto layout
    perm.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return perm
}()
```

After that I add programmatically some constraints. When I run the app the `title` is displayed in the right position, but the `view`'s background color has not been set.

**EDIT**

This is how I've set the constraints:

```
view.addSubview(title)

view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
title.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.superview!.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
```

Comment: show how you set constraints

Comment: I've edited them in :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`view` needs a height

```
view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:200).isActive = true
```

OR For label height plus top and bottom padding 40

```
title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.topAnchor, constant:20).isActive = true
```